# Saving a data to two different nodes with same node id?

Tags: nodes

I am having this problem , i want to save the same data into two tables with the same node id. I want to use both the tables on two different places because data is changing in the first table and i want to keep a track to the older data in my second table.

```
$node->field_call_response['und'][0]['tid'] = $call_response;
$node_new->field_log_response['und'][0]['tid'] = $call_response;
```

Comment: That's what revisions are for.

Comment: Suggestion: if the existing answer does not help for your case, then EDIT (extend) your question by (a) referring to that answer and (b) explaining why your question is not answered by that answer. OK?

Answer (score 0):

As Paul commented, there is already a system to keep track of changes. You can enable node revisioning through the UI by going to Config > Structure > Content types > [Content Type] > Edit and select the `Create new revision` option under `Publishing options`. Now every on-site node edit will be registered as a revision and the previous values are logged in the Revisions tab (next to edit).

If you need to programmatically create a new revision, you can do it as follows:

```
$node = node_load($nid);

$node->field_call_response['und'][0]['tid'] = $call_response;

$node->revision = 1; // Save new revision
$node->log = "Explain what you changed";
node_save($node);
```

Comment: $node = node_load($nid); i tried this but not working...:)

Comment: What is not working? You need to enter an existing node id as the value for `$nid`.